# Loop in python script with xpath. Why do I only get results form last url?

Tags: python, xpath

Why do I only get the results form the last url?
The idea is that I get a list of results of both urls.

Also, with the printing in csv I get eacht time an empty row. How do I remove this row?

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib

TV_category = ["_108-tot-127-cm-43-tot-50-,98952,501090","_128-tot-150-cm-51-tot-59-,98952,501091"]
url_pattern = 'http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/{}.html?langId=-17'

for item in TV_category:
    url = url_pattern.format(item)
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    outfile = open("./tv_test1.csv", "wb")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)    

    rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="category"]/ul[2]/li')


for row in rows:
    price = row.xpath('normalize-space(div/aside[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text())')
    product_ref = row.xpath('normalize-space(div/div/h2/a/text())')
    writer.writerow([product_ref,price])
```

Comment: Why do you open the file inside the loop?

Comment: **rows** should be a list, otherwise it would be replaced in every loop. Other way is moving the last for loop inside the first one.

Comment: How do you mean Andrés? Could you show me as I can't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: What do you think opening the file with "wb" is doing each time? Also your xpaths look pretty fragile

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in the question's comments, you need to put the second **for** loop inside (at the end) the first one. Otherwise, only the last **rows** results will be saved/written to the CSV-format file.

You don't need to open the file in each loop (a **with** statement will close it automagically). It is, as well, important to highlight that if you open a file with write flags it will overwrite, and if it's inside a loop it will overwrite each time it's opened.

I'd refactor your code as follows:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib

TV_category = ["_108-tot-127-cm-43-tot-50-,98952,501090","_128-tot-150-cm-51-tot-59-,98952,501091"]
url_pattern = 'http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/{}.html?langId=-17'

with open("./tv_test1.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for item in TV_category:
        url = url_pattern.format(item)
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)  
        rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="category"]/ul[2]/li')

        for row in rows:
            price = row.xpath('normalize-space(div/aside[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text())')
            product_ref = row.xpath('normalize-space(div/div/h2/a/text())')
            writer.writerow([product_ref,price])
```